# How do I implement Android Firebase dynamic links without a website?

Tags: android, firebase, dynamic-linking, firebase-invites

I have an Android app published in the Play Store. I want to use the Firebase invites, but it seems that I need dynamic links and I don't have a website to create one.

What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a website to create dynamic links, you merely need to [enable "Dynamic Links" (and accept the terms of service)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android#before-you-begin) in the [API console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) so that Firebase Invites can leverage that API to create its own dynamic links on your behalf.

Comment: Are you sure? But what links do I provide to the API?

Comment: If you're talking about the `deepLink` parameter, you'll want to read about [Deep Linking in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

Comment: I'm not talking about that. I want the user to send a Firebase invite to their friends, and that firebase invite must contain a Firebase dynamic link, doesn't it?

Comment: The generated Invite is itself a Dynamic Link that either opens your app or navigates to the Play store. From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/#how_does_it_work): "Invitations are sent by email or SMS ... and contain a Dynamic Link to your app."

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I got it now.

Comment: @rymo The link that is sent as "Install" button via email or SMS is different than the dynamic links provided by the firebase. And both have different behavior. For example, In case of Invite link, 1. you can easily attach referral code, 2. If you open the link from desktop browser then it always redirects to play store while in case of dynamic links it redirects to our website set on firebase console. I am wondering how to use dynamic link that contains referral code and other information as Invites.